# Converting Python Groupby and aggregate to Postgres SQL

Tags: pandas, postgresql, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a table called `cnms_table` in my PostgresSQL database that is equivalent to a pandas dataframe called `cnms_df` that I created in a Python script. In the Python dataframe, I was able to use `groupby` and `agg` to summarize and aggregate the dataframe based on specific columns/fields to create a new summarized dataframe called `sum_df`.

```
 sum_df_prelim = cnms_df.groupby(['Region', 'State',  'CO_FIPS', 'Tiermetric_Prelim',
                              'Mod_unMod_Prelim', 'Val_Combined_Prelim', 'Det_Approx_Prelim',
                              'Decay_Date_Prelim'], as_index=False).agg({'Actual_Miles_Prelim': 'sum'})
```

How would I do this in a Postgres SQL query or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(Actual_Miles_Prelim)
FROM
  cnms_table
GROUP BY
  'Region',
  'State',
  'CO_FIPS',
  'Tiermetric_Prelim',
  'Mod_unMod_Prelim',
  'Val_Combined_Prelim', 
  'Det_Approx_Prelim',
  'Decay_Date_Prelim'
```

Comment: This worked but only after I removed the ' 's from the column names. Thanks.